How to format and recover a messy a SD card? The data on the card doesn’t matter; I just want to have the SD card usable again
There is a messy SD card that I want to wipe out all data and partition table.

I have already tried it in windows with diskpart.
And exception detail on event log :

"Cannot zero sectors on disk \?\PhysicalDrive2. Error code: 5@0101000F"


Also I have tried to write 00 to all sd card sectors. But card does not allow to writing from sector 16 to last sector.
I have Linux environment and tried lots of tools like gparted, fdisk, etc and could not format the SD card. I would like to hear any alternative ways.

Your title says 'recover', your text says 'I want to wipe'. What is it? In the latter case, just use a hammer.

recovery is not the issue. I want to format sd card and make it usable again. Files on it is not the case. Title has been updated not by me.

Look into using the official SD Association card formatter; it is available for Windows and macOS.
It can apparently revive once thought unusable SD cards as explained here:

“However, once trying the SD Association's formatting utility, the card with bad blocks no longer had any bad blocks (though showed up as about 1GB smaller than before), and the other SD card that was running at about 1/4th it's normal speed was back up to about 90% of it's advertised speed.”


Unfourtunately, formating failed with that tool.

If so the card is dead.

Not sure about it

@asahin - not sure about what? SD cards have a limited lifespan. If the formatter described in this answer fails, then the SD card has failed

I have 2 sd cards and they have same error at same time. Do you think they have been corrupted at the same time? A coincidence?
